# How to write this autoloader PSR-0/1/2 save?

Tags: php, syntax, psr-0

The PSR-0/1/2-syntax checker on [phphint.org](http://phphint.org/analyze) gives this message

```
The first parameter of a multi-line function declaration must be on
the line after the opening bracket
```

on this code:

```
// class autoloader for PHP 5.3+
spl_autoload_register( function ($class) {
    include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
});
```

I tried a lot, but never got this little piece of code PSR-0/1/2-save.
How would a solution look like (or is the analyzer on phphint too strict ?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by myself, but the solution is extremely ugly.

```
spl_autoload_register( function (
    $class
) {
    include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
}
);
```

Maybe the PSR-guys should think about their weird syntax.
The correct solution looks like this, even if it is a step backwards.

```
// autoload function (it's NOT "__autoload", __autoload is
// DEPRECATED since PHP 5.4!)
function autoload($class) {
    include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
}

// class autoloader for PHP 5.3+, registers the function that's used if a class/file
// is not found (=autoloader)
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Comment: here's the PSR-2 syntax doc for this https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#6-closures

Comment: NOTICE: JanL edited this today, but now it's not PSR-safe anymore (according to the official PSR-checking tool). Yes, it's more readable now, but also broken. So I re-edited this thing to the old version.

Comment: Using PSR-1 and PSR-2 is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

*As of PHP 5.3.0 it is possible to also pass a closure to a callback parameter.*

So, what you are doing seems perfectly allright to me.

You could see if phphint.org agrees on this:

```
$lambda = function ($class) { include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php'); };
spl_autoload_register( $lambda );
```